# AWS cft "fn::if" shows error

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I'am using the below line in my template

```
     "ec2instance" : {
"Type" : "AWS::EC2::Instance",
"Properties" : {
        "InstanceType" : {"Ref" : "Publicinstancetype"},
        "ImageId" : "<myimageid>",
        "SubnetId" : { "Fn::If" : ["createpublicsubnet",{"Ref":"publicsubnet"},
        {"Fn::If" : ["createprivatesubnet",{"Ref":"privatesubnet"}]}
        ]}
}
```

}
it is displaying as "Template error: Fn::If requires a list argument with three elements" where am I exactly going wrong? AWS documentations aren't helping. I have specified the conditions perfectly so no need top bother about it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Fn:In` requires 3 elements and you are giving only 2 parameters.

See the AWS documentation Example . 

`"SecurityGroups" : [{
  "Fn::If" : [
    "CreateNewSecurityGroup",
    {"Ref" : "NewSecurityGroup"},
    {"Ref" : "ExistingSecurityGroup"}
  ]
}]`

"SubnetId" : { "Fn::If" : ["createpublicsubnet",{"Ref":"publicsubnet"},

It should have been
"SubnetId" : { "Fn::If" : ["createpublicsubnet",{"Ref":"publicsubnet"}, {"Ref:"privatesubnet"}]}

In your code , it has only two elements been passed as .

Check the AWS documentation correctly. 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-conditions.html#intrinsic-function-reference-conditions-if

Answer (score 1):

Since the Fn::If function requires 3 arguments, you need to use a pseudoparameter:

```
    "ec2instance" : {
        "Type" : "AWS::EC2::Instance",
        "Properties" : {
            "InstanceType" : {"Ref" : "Publicinstancetype"},
            "ImageId" : "<myimageid>",
            "SubnetId" : {
                "Fn::If" : [
                    "createpublicsubnet",
                    {"Ref" : "publicsubnet"},
                    {"Fn::If" : [
                        "createprivatesubnet",
                        {"Ref" : "privatesubnet"},
                        {"Ref" : "AWS::NoValue"}   // Here
                    ]}
                ]
            }
        }
    }
```